# jquery delay/animate start bugging after some time and overlapping

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got to work on a piece of jQuery code that runs a simple slider of three images, it shows and hides them one by one, and should repeat the process indefinitely.

here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function start_slider() {

        $('#slider_img_1').animate({
            top: '-=495'
        }, 1000).delay(4000).animate({
            top: '+=495'
        }, 1000);
        $('#slider_img_2').delay(6000).animate({
            top: '-=495'
        }, 1000).delay(4000).animate({
            top: '+=495'
        }, 1000);
        $('#slider_img_3').delay(12000).animate({
            top: '-=495'
        }, 1000).delay(4000).animate({
            top: '+=495'
        }, 1000);
        setTimeout(function () {
            start_slider();
        }, 18000);
    }
    start_slider();
});
```

Now as far i understand this, it animates the first picture for 1s, holds it for 4s and animates it back for 1s. Does the same for other 2. The math fits in? it last for 18s in total and then it starts again.

**Problem:** *It works perfectly for maybe 3-5min, then i see 2 images that overlap once. After 10min the start overlapping more often and it increases slowly over time.*

What could be the problem? (Note: same bug in firefox and chrome)

Comment: Your approach is not scalable and as animation is not millisecond-perfect, it will not take precisely 18 seconds to complete, so overlapping is to be expected with your approach. You should take a look at animation chaining and `promise()`, or use an extension such as [jQuery-timing](http://creativecouple.github.io/jquery-timing/). You can see a similar situation handled [here](http://jsfiddle.net/uWGVN/2/).

Comment: ok, i'll test it today and see how it goes. Thnx